# I cant get my SQL INSERT statement to work with 2 tables in relationship in Delphi7

Tags: sql, delphi, ms-access, delphi-7

I Keep getting the following error

> Project PAT_p.exe raised exception class EOleException with message 'Current provider does not support returning multiple recordsets from a single execution'. Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.

My tables in my database are linked in a one-to-many relationship where ID is the PK in tblDeelname and Nommer is a autonumber and the PK in tblAntwoorde. Unfortunately this is for a Practical assessment task at school and the relationship have to be there.
My Delphi code is as follow:

```
Procedure TfrmDN.btnBDClick(Sender: TObject);
var

sNaam, sVan, sKNommer, sAntwoord, sInteger : string;

begin

 sNaam := lblNaam2.Caption;              //
 sVan := lblVan2.Caption;                //Declaring Strings
 sKNommer := lblKN2.Caption;             //
 sAntwoord := lblAntwoord1.Caption;      //
 inc(iTInskrywings);          // Global var starting at 100 which is declared on form activate
 sInteger := intostr(iTInskrywings);

 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := false;    // query is on another form
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'insert into tblDeelnemers (ID, Naam, Van, Kontaknommer) VALUES ("'+sInteger+'", "'+sNaam+'", "'+sVan+'","'+sKNommer+'")'; // Inserting Data into first Table
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'insert into tblAntwoorde (ID, Antwoord) VALUES ("'+sInteger+'", "'+sAntwoord+'")';   // Inserting Data into second Table
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := true;

end;
```

All the info going into the tables come from edit boxes and the ID is a global variable(Also apart of the assessment that have to be there). I made the Integer into a String due to another error that appeared before this one witch did not want me to insert a integer value with sql.

PLEASE HELP!!!

Comment: Why are you setting the `qryVGKompetisieDB.Active` to True at the end of you insertion ? What happens if you execute those SQL queries in your DB management tool ? What is your database engine ?

Comment: @TLama i am making the quarry true because it displays in a dbgrid. I am not sure how to use it in my DM management tool. I am using Microsoft Access

Comment: At least one problem I can see is that you're trying to open a dataset on the `INSERT` query. You've set the `SQL.Text` to `INSERT` query and executed it, but it doesn't change it back to a `SELECT` query after that. You must set the `SQL.Text` to some `SELECT` query and then set `Active` to True.

Comment: @TLama Thank you a lot that was the problem. I just added a select statement after the execute and it worked. I don't suppose you can look at my other question about the delete in sql. IT is here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685250/how-can-i-delete-all-data-with-sql-in-2-tables-which-is-in-a-relationship-in-del)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @TLama I corrected my stupid mistake by only adding the select statement after the last execute.

```
Procedure TfrmDN.btnBDClick(Sender: TObject);
var

sNaam, sVan, sKNommer, sAntwoord, sInteger : string;

begin

 sNaam := lblNaam2.Caption;              
 sVan := lblVan2.Caption;                
 sKNommer := lblKN2.Caption;             
 sAntwoord := lblAntwoord1.Caption;      
 inc(iTInskrywings);          
 sInteger := intostr(iTInskrywings);

 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := false;    
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'insert into tblDeelnemers (ID, Naam, Van, Kontaknommer) VALUES ("'+sInteger+'", "'+sNaam+'", "'+sVan+'","'+sKNommer+'")'; 
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'insert into tblAntwoorde (ID, Antwoord) VALUES ("'+sInteger+'", "'+sAntwoord+'")';   
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.ExecSQL;
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM tblDeelnemers'; // The select statement needs to be there so that the dbgrid can display properly  
 frmData.qryVGKompetisieDB.Active := true;

end;
```

Comment: @DavidG I can't accept it as a answer because it is post as a comment and not a answer :/